# ExtJS - Attributes changes are being ignored during drag action

Tags: drag-and-drop, extjs4.2

We are using ExtJS 4.2.1. The width/height attributes of the img won't change in below example when element is dragged beyond the +/-5px y-coordinate. Changes to attribute 'show' are also ignored. However, element can be destroyed and re-created, but this is not desired.

```js
[panel]
var dndLinkSprite = me.surface.add({                               
    type: 'image',
    x: bBox.x,
    y: bBox.y,
    width: 16,
    height: 16,
    src: '/link.png'
})

...

dragAction: function(panel, e, diff, dndConfig) {
    var spriteLink = panel.dndLinkSprite;
    if ( diff[1] > 5 || diff[1] < -5 ) {
        spriteLink.setAttributes(height, 16);
        spriteLink.setAttributes(width, 16);
    } else {
        spriteLink.setAttributes(height, 0);
        spriteLink.setAttributes(width, 0);        
    };
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved - wrong syntax:

Instead of:

```js
spriteLink.setAttributes(height, 0);
spriteLink.setAttributes(width, 0);
```

use:

```js
spriteLink.setAttributes({width: 0, height:0} , true);
```

Answer (score -1):

spriteLink.getEl().dom.setAttribute(height, 16);

Comment: Thanks YangYang. This might be the right approach. Only problem is that I get a   "Uncaught TypeError: spriteLink.getEl is not a function" when using " spriteLink.getEl().dom.setAttribute(height, 16);"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.